# Fetch - is there an easier way to convert this to an array or a readable format where I can loop through it?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

If I use 'application/text' and `res.text()`, it returns plain text and not an array.
If I use `res.json()`, I get an invalid token at the end '<'
If I `JSON.stringify(final)`, I get a string of extra new line characters that are not parseable.
Is there another way to ready this from a public folder?

This is the sample file structure I was given, not a json but an array of object entities:

filename: newFile.dto

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    img: 'C:\\ReactProjects\\IMAGES\\DSC_0134.jpg',
    test: 'another column'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    img: 'C:\\ReactProjects\\IMAGES\\DSC_0135.jpg',
    test: 'another column 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: 'C:\\ReactProjects\\IMAGES\\DSC_0136.jpg',
    test: 'another column 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: 'C:\\ReactProjects\\IMAGES\\DSC_0137.jpg',
    test: 'another column 3'
  }
]


  async function testFileRead()
  {
     let myArray = await fetch('newFile.dto',{
        headers : { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/text',
          'Accept': 'application/text'
         }
       }
      )
      .then(res =>{
        return res.text(); //res.json()
      })
      .then(final =>{
        return final;
      })
  }
```

Comment: The file isn't JSON format. In JSON, strings must be in double quotes, not single quotes. And object keys must be quoted.

Comment: yes, it's a DTO format, that's why it's difficult to parse, if it's a json format, I think I could just import it directly. I tried to Stringify it, but the result has full of double quotes and new line characters, which is not I was looking for. I want to simple read it as an object so I can loop through the properties.

Comment: DTO is a TypeScript facility. Maybe you can load the DTO library into ordinary JavaScript, and use that.

Comment: Stringifying text just returns the JSON format of a string, it won't parse the DTO format.

Comment: If you know the source of the data (trust it).  You can just use `eval`.  `return eval(await res.text())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval()` after `fetch`:

```js
  console.log("data", myArray); //text as string
  console.log("eval", eval(myArray)); //array JS
```

[image]
**Note** [***Never use eval()!***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval): Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk.

As ***Keith*** suggest use at leas is safer than `eval`:

```js
  const arr = new Function("return [..." + myArray + "]")();
  console.log(arr.map((obj) => obj.test));// ['another column', 'another column 1', 'another column 2', 'another column 3']
```

Comment: `Never use eval()!`  Bit extreme there from MDN :),  but you could also do the Function version that seems to have less security issues.   `new Function('return [...]')()`

Comment: Good way and much more safer, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm using new Function.